# QRCode from a file using IOS 7 API

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation, qr-code

I know there is third parties alternatives, but I would like to know if it's possible using the **iOS 7 API**.

Since **iOS 7 AVFoundation** can parse QRCode in real time. [Example](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/)

Is it possible to use this API but for a image in a file? Using for exemple a image as input device(?) or other solution?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, though you will have to use a slightly different API.

The example you linked to uses `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, which makes integration easy in the AVFoundation framework, especially for real-time video.

In the case of a single still image, it's easier to use a [`CIDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/) with the appropriate type (`CIDetectorTypeQRCode`).

A full example of the use of `CIDetector` can be found in [Detecting Faces in an Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html) in the Core Image Programming Guide. You'll just have to switch the type you want.